# Upgrading maven from 3.0.5 from 3.1.0

Tags: java, maven

I am currently using maven 3.0.5 with my java web project. That artifact uses the RepositarySystem class to read maven artifact. This project running fine with no issues. But when I am trying to upgrade maven version then The aether.RepositorySystem throws error.

I've referred some online documents and came to know about Maven started providing RepositorySystem from org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem rather already provided Jar from org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem.

But the problem now I want my project runs with no error on version 3.0.5 as well as latest versions. Is there any possibility to load the class file according to the maven version.

Please guide me to get rid of this error? Thanks in advance.

My stack trace follows,

```
[PhrescoException]:  [ErrorMessage] = [PhrescoException]:  [ErrorMessage] = org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

    No implementation for java.util.Set<org.eclipse.aether.RepositoryListener> was bound.
      while locating java.util.Set<org.eclipse.aether.RepositoryListener>
        for parameter 0 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryEventDispatcher.<init>(Unknown Source)
      while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryEventDispatcher
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.RepositoryEventDispatcher
        for parameter 0 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.<init>(Unknown Source)
      while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.MetadataResolver
        for parameter 0 at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver.<init>(Unknown Source)
      while locating org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultVersionResolver
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      while locating org.eclipse.aether.impl.VersionResolver
        for parameter 0 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.<init>(Unknown Source)
      while locating org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
      while locating org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem
```

Comment: Why not 3.1.1 which has some relevant looking bugfixes?

Comment: Nope Gimby. I couldn't run this on any of the maven version after 3.0.5 because after this maven provides the aethor api from org.eclipse.

Comment: Are you developing a maven plugin or what are you doing? Can you show some code snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface which you use everywhere where you right now use aether.RepositorySystem or related classes.

Write two implementations, one based on the old version, one on the new version.

Finally create a little Factory which tries to instantiate the implementation based on the new version. Wrap that in a try catch block and if it fails create one based on the old version.

The result should look somewhat like this

```
public interface RepositorySystem {

    public void doStuff() // add whatever methods you need here

    public DetailWrapper getDetails() // maybe you need more wrapper interfaces and matching implementations, when you aren't dealing with just one class.
}

public class RepositorySystemAdapterPreMavenXXX implements RepositorySystem {
    org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem delegate = new org.sonatype.aether.RepositorySystem();
    public void doStuff(){
        delegate.doStuff();
    }

    // ...
}

public class RepositorySystemAdapterPostMavenXXX implements RepositorySystem {
    org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem delegate = new org.eclipse.aether.RepositorySystem();
    public void doStuff(){
        delegate.doStuff();
    }

    // ...
}

public class RepositorySystemFactory{
    public static RepositorySystem repositorySystem(){
        try {
            return new RepositorySystemAdapterPostMavenXXX(); // you might have to use reflection to do this ... not completely sure;
        } catch(Error error) { // find out what kind of error/exception you get and catch exactly that
            return  new RepositorySystemAdapterPreMavenXXX();
        }
    }
}
```

The two implementations will have to go in seperate jars build with seperate versions of Maven.

Comment: Thanks Jens.. Hope You are getting me. Kindly provide some code snippets for this. because I'm new to maven versions. It helps more when you back with some code.